# Flickr API image unavailable windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, flickr

I'm trying to use flicke's api to import images into a Windows Phone app and display them on the phones panoramic dispaly.

I'm new to flickr's API and am stuck ATM.

I've tried the following call:

```
             // original string flickString = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=cc9babb2754c1d29837bea480c97013e&text=game+of+thrones&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_sig=bb86a60e9e42f31950bf53d25fc45f08";
        string flickString = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=cc9babb2754c1d29837bea480c97013e&text=game+of+thrones&extras=url_sq%2C+url_t%2C+url_s%2C+url_q%2C+url_m%2C+url_n%2C+url_z%2C+url_c%2C+url_l%2C+url_o+&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_sig=9e74e094d8c6a7496fc66e070f5c0898";

        var baseUrl = string.Format(flickString, flickrAPIKey);

        string flickrResult = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);

        FlickrData flickrApiData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlickrData>(flickrResult);

        if(flickrApiData.stat == "ok")
        {
            foreach (Photo data in flickrApiData.photos.photo)
            {
                // To retrieve one photo
                // http://farm{farmid}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}{size}.jpeg

                //string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}_o.jpeg";
                //string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}_b.jpeg";
                //string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}_n.jpg";
                string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}"

                string baseFlickrUrl = string.Format(photoUrl,
                    data.farm,
                    data.server,
                    data.id,
                    data.secret);

                flickr1Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(baseFlickrUrl));

                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

When I deploy and run the app I get an image saying that this image is unavailiablemessage every time? I've tried changing the search terms etc and still get the sme message. Which is making me wondor if I've missed something setting up my account with flickr earlier that I'm not aware of? It's very frustrating - help please.

Thanks to card_master for his help so far

Answer (score 1):

I'm also integrating with Flickr.  I'm creating a web site that uses their api.

I'm using [FlickrNet](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/).  This is an open source .net library that you can use to call the Flickr Services.  This is a C# library.

The benefit of using it on a mobile application you can take advantage of the caching.  It allows you to store images in the phones storage.  This won't work on a web application though.